# How to change the black hover background on navbar moves automatically when scrolling down

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend, jsx, web-frontend

this time i want to ask how to change the black hover background on navbar moves automatically when scrolling down , i use react and here is the jsx and css code:

**nav.jsx**

```
import React from 'react'
import './nav.css'
import {AiOutlineHome} from 'react-icons/ai'
import {AiOutlineUser} from 'react-icons/ai'
import {BiBook} from 'react-icons/bi'
import {RiServiceLine} from 'react-icons/ri'
import {BiMessageSquareDetail} from 'react-icons/bi'
import { useState } from 'react'


const Nav = () => {
  const[activeNav,setActiveNav]=useState('#')
  return (
    <nav>
      <a href="#" onClick={()=>setActiveNav('#')} className={activeNav === '#' ? 'active' : ''}><AiOutlineHome /></a>
      <a href="#about" onClick={()=>setActiveNav('#about')} className={activeNav === '#about' ? 'active' : ''} ><AiOutlineUser /></a>
      <a href="#experience" onClick={()=>setActiveNav('#experience')} className={activeNav === '#experience' ? 'active' : ''}><BiBook /></a>
      <a href="#portfolio" onClick={()=>setActiveNav('#portfolio')} className={activeNav === '#portfolio' ? 'active' : ''}><RiServiceLine /></a>
      <a href="#contact" onClick={()=>setActiveNav('#contact')} className={activeNav === '#contact' ? 'active' : ''}><BiMessageSquareDetail /></a>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Nav
```

**nav.css**

```
nav{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    width: max-content;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.7rem 1.7rem;
    z-index: 2;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    bottom: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    gap: 0.8rem;
    border-radius: 3rem;
    backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
}

nav a{
    background: transparent;
    padding: 0.9rem;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: flex;
    color: var(--color-light);
    font-size: 1.1rem;
}

nav a:hover{
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

nav a.active{
    background: var(--color-bg);
    color:var(--color-white);
}
```

here is the [video](https://youtu.be/uPqVqY5lfiw) demonstration of the navbar and i'am confuse how to make the hover background icon move by the section automatically when scrolling down. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve that using a package called `react-scroll`, it acts as a regular link, and you can set an active class as well, and using the `spy={true}` option, which makes the Link selected when the scroll is at its targets position aka anchor tag.

for more information check:
[react-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll) on npm.